# CCLabelBMFont crashing without notice?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I got these two methods in my scene:

```
-(void)damageText:(NSString*)text atPosition:(CGPoint)position {
    CCLabelBMFont *label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:text fntFile:@"Font2.fnt"];
    label.position = position;
    [self addChild:label z:50];
    label.scale = 0.01;
    [label runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.08 scale:1.0],
                      [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.2],[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.8],
                      [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(killLabel:)],nil]];
    label.opacity = 0;
    [label runAction:[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:0.04]];
}

-(void)killLabel:(id)sender {
    CCLabelBMFont *label = (CCLabelBMFont*)sender;
    [self removeChild:label cleanup:YES];
}
```

So first, I use the **damageText** method, and my message pops up alright. Then it fades out and it is removed from the scene.

But the SECOND time I do this, it crashes, with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS message saying

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'TextureCache: fileimage MUST not be nill'

But I don't quite understand. If it did find Font2.png before, why is it failing the second time?

I suspect **CCLabelBMFont.m** didn't properly load the **configuration_** variable at line

```
configuration_ = FNTConfigLoadFile(fntFile);
```

Because when I try to NSLog it, I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal.

Comment: Okay, I have discovered that if I don't remove the label from the scene's children, the error won't occur. But heck, then I how would I dispose of... well, the label itself? Won't it stack memory?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment I think you may be onto a solution that might work.  Instead of calling...

```
 CCLabelBMFont *label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:text fntFile:@"Font2.fnt"];
```

everytime in `damageText` why not just have a member variable you initiate in the constructor and then set the text only in the `damageText` function.  So you would end up with..

```
-(void)damageText:(NSString*)text atPosition:(CGPoint)position {
    // CCLabelBMFont *label = [CCLabelBMFont labelWithString:text fntFile:@"Font2.fnt"];
    label.position = position;
    //[self addChild:label z:50];
    label.scale = 0.01;
    [label runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCScaleTo actionWithDuration:0.08 scale:1.0],
                      [CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:0.2],[CCFadeOut actionWithDuration:0.8],
                      [CCCallFuncN actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(killLabel:)],nil]];
    label.opacity = 0;
    [label runAction:[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:0.04]];
}
```

I wouldn't even worry about removing the label either.  Let the parent of the label take care of that (I'm assuming a CCLayer or CCScene object?) when it gets deallocated.   If you want to remove the label from view just set its visibility to false or its scale to 0.

**UPDATE**: Took out the addChild call as well.  You only need to do this once and can likely be done in the constructor.